How to analyze a variant of the prisoner's dilemma?
In most versions of the prisoner's dilemma I have seen, confessing is the dominant strategy for both prisoners, like this one.
However, I am interested in the following case with a change on numbers. So, if we change $(2,2)$ at the bottom right to $(4,4)$, i.e. if they both testify then they are both sentenced to four years instead of two.
In the original example, if both choose their respective dominant strategy, then it leads to the unique Nash equilibrium but this outcome is less efficient than the choice if they both stay silent. Nevertheless, this does make sense since the game has imperfect information and therefore choosing the dominant strategy can be analyzed logically.
However, in my example, neither testifying or staying silent is a dominant strategy for either player. The two Nash equilibria are those on the top right and bottom left (one testifies and one stays silent).
But I am not sure how one shall argue that any choice out of four is the most "reasonable" choice: Staying silent is the min-max strategy for both players, so it might make sense to say both want to do so. However, if we argue in this way, and conventionally assume both are rational, then player 1 would "infer" that player 2 will choose to stay silent, then player 1 would prefer to confess to further reduce the sentence. But this inference is symmetric, so player 2 will also end up confessing. The final outcome would be both staying silent, which is the worst outcome for both players.
I would appreciate any insights or resources that can break this symmetry and provide a rigorous argument that any of the other three possibilities is a reasonable outcome (an equilibrium of a type, for instance). Thanks!

Is your variant now a game of Chicken?

In modern game theory, because it is possible to construct games where there is no deterministic equilibrium, it is standard to study the games in terms of mixed strategies. That is, rather than each player making a fixed decision, they instead randomly choose from their options with some predetermined probability distribution.
In this case, the strategy for player A would be described as confessing with probability $p_A$ and staying silent with probability $1 - p_A$, and similarly for player B. Then the expected value of the game for player A, conditional on $p_B$ can be calculated as
$$E(A | p_B) = 2 p_A p_B + 0 p_A (1 - p_B) + 3 (1 - p_A) p_B + 2 (1 - p_A)(1 - p_B)$$
That expression will then have a value of $p_A$ in the interval $[0, 1]$ that minimises it, and similarly there will be a value of $p_B$ that minimises B's expected sentence. As a result, you can find values of $(p_A, p_B)$ such that both prisoners' expected value is at a local minimum - i.e. if either of them changes their strategy slightly in any direction, they can expect a longer sentence. That strategy is the Nash equilibrium for your version of the game.
If you apply the same analysis to the traditional dilemma, you'll find that this equilibrium happens at $p_A = p_B = 1$, i.e. always confessing.

Thanks for your answer! Although in this case, there are indeed two Nash equilibria (one stays silent and the other confesses). But as usual they do not communicate with each other before making decisions, so I was wondering whether there is an established theory that can justifies the choice of any pure strategies in this case, especially the top left one since this maximizes their collective welfare. However, since we assume they are both rational, they don't care about the other's welfare, but they don't trust each other either. It seems a circular reasoning.

If they are both cautious, then each player would be silent. I am also interested in the case that they are both "informative", meaning that each player knows that the other player is cautious and would choose to be silent, but in this case, each player would want to confess to minimize its own sentence, but this also applies to the other player. This would be another infinite loop. I would appreciate any insights that can break this

The existence of loops is exactly why mixed strategies are studied over pure ones. Anything beyond that requires you to change the assumptions in how they make their decisions - as long as the assumption is "both players are rational, cannot collude, and always try to make the decision that gives them the best relative outcome" you will reach the same conclusions.
